# How to check for internat connection on a specified port and ip address

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, networking, frameworks

how do I check for an internet connection on a specified port and ip address instead of the default system proxy (My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable). Thanks

Comment: a network connection is independent of port. Do you mean check for external access on a port?

Comment: @MitchWheat Yeah, like if I had a proxy server

Answer (score 0):

Just try to connect to it. If it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the Socket class:

```
bool isConnected = true;

try
{
  Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

  s.Connect(yourIpAddress, yourPort);

  byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testing");

  s.Send(msg);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
  isConnected = false;
}
```